# How can I get Webpack to load folders from my node_modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I recently installed tinyMCE via npm.  In the node_modules folder, I see it has a bunch of subfolders for icons, plugins, etc.

In my app, I am importing them like this:

```
import 'tinymce/plugins/image';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';
```

But for every `import`, I get an error like this:

```
GET http://localhost:16942/dist/plugins/visualblocks/plugin.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load plugin: visualblocks from url plugins/visualblocks/plugin.js
```

I see that it is looking in the `dist` folder.

So I copied all the needed subfolders into there.

But everytime I run the app in Visual Studio, those subfolders go missing.

I think it has to with webpack.

Is there a way to have webpack copy those in at runtime or not delete them?

Thanks

Comment: I think your import statements are wrong, try to get the import statement form their docs. https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/

Comment: @Onix I am hosting tinymce locally and I need to load the files locally.  I am trying to base my install as found on this site: [How to setup TinyMCE + React](https://dev.to/rafaaraujoo/how-to-setup-tinymce-react-4aka)